# How to separate blog post into another git repo when creating website using a static site generator?

Tags: git, github, markdown, jekyll, static-site

I have a git repo called `notes` which contains all the blog posts in markdown inside the markdown directory and the images it is referencing in the images folder like so.

```
notes
 - markdown
   - Date-Blog-Title-1.markdown
   - Date-Blog-Title-2.markdown
   - ...
 - images
   - image1.png
   - image2.png
   - ...
```

How do I have another git repo which uses the content on my `notes` repo to generate a website using a `static site generator` such as `jekyll`, `octopress`, `pelican` which I can host on `github` or `gitlab`?

Answer (score 2):

I do just about the same thing (I have a separate repository that contains only markdown files and any associated assets, like image files).  I use Pelican as a static site generator.

I have the pelican site directory checked out locally, and then inside that I have checked out the content repository.  It's not even a git submodule: it's just one git repo inside another git repo on my local filesystem.  Git knows to ignore the embedded repository when looking for new files, etc.

Comment: Where can I find your repo? Do you have it on github? I would like to see how have you done it. How do you have the repo on github without using git submodule?

Comment: There's really nothing to see in the repos, because they are completely separate.  The content is https://github.com/larsks/blog.oddbit.com-posts and the pelican config is https://github.com/larsks/blog.oddbit.com. Locally, I have the content repository checked out into a "content" subdirectory of the pelican repository.

Comment: What about if you want to create multiple version of site using the same content. ie: using different themes or one created using jekyll and another created using pelican?

Comment: For experimenting with themes I would just branch the pelican repository. For using another site generator,either a symlink or just another clone of the content.

Comment: When branching, would you be able to have multiple sites hosted using github pages. When using symlink, what happens when you commit the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Github Pages allows you to host from a specific branch. This means you can commit your `content` code, allows travis-ci or similar to build the website to the branch `gh-pages`, and then serve the content from there:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages

(you can also take a look at my website [workflow](https://github.com/philshem/smalldata.github.io), and in particular, the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/philshem/smalldata.github.io/blob/master/.travis.yml) file). In this case, `make github` is as simple as can be.